# Multiple Validation + $.validator on single field

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

How can call multiple validation functions on single field in jQuery.

as below

Multiple Validation on line:

**JobDayofWeek: { isValidJOW: true },
JobDayofWeek: { regex: "^[1-7]$|^(\s*[1-7]+\s*,\s*)+[1-7]$" },**

```
var isValidJOW = function isJOWValid(value) {
        var newTemp = getDataforNewTemplate();
        if (newTemp.AutoResubmitFlag == 'N' && value == '') {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

 $.validator.addMethod("isValidJOW", function (value, element) {
        var newTemp = getDataforNewTemplate();
        return isValidJOW(newTemp.JobDayofWeek);
    }, 'Job Day of Week Mandatory when auto resubmit flag is set to Y');

    $.validator.addMethod("regex", function (value, element, regexp) {
        var check = false;
        var re = new RegExp(regexp);
        return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
    }, "The list of values 1(Sunday) to 7 (Saturday).  For multiples enter the following 1,2,3...");


     $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#maintTempForm").validate({
            rules: {
                JobTypes: { isValidJobType: true },
                ExecutableName: { required: true },
                ExecutableType: { isValidJExecutableType: true },
                JobDayofWeek: { isValidJOW: true },
                JobDayofWeek: { regex: "^[1-7]$|^(\s*[1-7]+\s*,\s*)+[1-7]$" },
                JobFrequency: { regexJobFrequency: "^[1-365]$" },
                AutoResubmitFlag: { isValidFlag: true }

            },
            messages: {
                ExecutableName: "Please Enter Valid Executable Name"

            }
        });
    });
```

This is always validating only the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rules:

```
rules: {
    //...
    JobDayofWeek: { isValidJOW: true },
    JobDayofWeek: { regex: "^[1-7]$|^(\s*[1-7]+\s*,\s*)+[1-7]$" }
    //...
}
```

are just an object literal and as such, cannot have multiple values for a single field. The JavaScript parser will only use one of the `JobDayofWeek` values when building the literal, which one it will use is probably implementation defined but maybe not.

What happens with this rule set?

```
rules: {
    JobTypes: { isValidJobType: true },
    ExecutableName: { required: true },
    ExecutableType: { isValidJExecutableType: true },
    JobDayofWeek: { isValidJOW: true, regex: "^[1-7]$|^(\s*[1-7]+\s*,\s*)+[1-7]$" },
    JobFrequency: { regexJobFrequency: "^[1-365]$" },
    AutoResubmitFlag: { isValidFlag: true }
},
```

All I did was combine the two `JobDayofWeek` values into one. That should work.